# MongoDB still shows empty collections after restoring from dump

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongorestore

After mongodump, I did mongorestore which seemed to work fine

```
heathers-air:db heathercohen$ mongorestore -v -host localhost:27017
2015-02-06T11:22:40.027-0800 creating new connection to:localhost:27017
2015-02-06T11:22:40.028-0800 [ConnectBG] BackgroundJob starting: ConnectBG
2015-02-06T11:22:40.028-0800 connected to server localhost:27017 (127.0.0.1)
2015-02-06T11:22:40.028-0800 connected connection!
connected to: localhost:27017
2015-02-06T11:22:40.030-0800 dump/langs.bson
2015-02-06T11:22:40.030-0800    going into namespace [dump.langs]
Restoring to dump.langs without dropping. Restored data will be inserted without raising errors; check your server log
file dump/langs.bson empty, skipping
2015-02-06T11:22:40.030-0800    Creating index: { key: { _id: 1 }, name: "_id_", ns: "dump.langs" }
2015-02-06T11:22:40.031-0800 dump/tweets.bson
2015-02-06T11:22:40.031-0800    going into namespace [dump.tweets]
Restoring to dump.tweets without dropping. Restored data will be inserted without raising errors; check your server log
     file size: 4877899
30597 objects found
2015-02-06T11:22:41.883-0800    Creating index: { key: { _id: 1 }, name: "_id_", ns: "dump.tweets" }
```

When I try to access the data though, it's still empty and the way it looked before restore:

```
> show dbs
admin    (empty)
dump     0.078GB
local    0.078GB
tweets   (empty)
twitter  (empty)
```

It says it found 30597 objects, where did they go?

Comment: The output states "Restored data will be inserted without raising errors; check your server log". Did you check the mongod.log file at that time for errors?

Comment: It reads
 `2015-02-06T11:23:31.847-0800 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52475 #21 (6 connections now open)
2015-02-06T11:23:55.287-0800 [clientcursormon] mem (MB) res:18 virt:2803
2015-02-06T11:23:55.287-0800 [clientcursormon]  mapped (incl journal view):320
2015-02-06T11:23:55.287-0800 [clientcursormon]  connections:6
2015-02-06T11:27:13.555-0800 [conn21] end connection 127.0.0.1:52475 (5 connections now open)` 
@JamesWahlin

Comment: can you switch to the dump database in the mongo shell using "use dump" and then run "show collections" and post the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They went into the dump database, and then into the collections `dump.tweets` and `dump.langs`. The fact that the files are contained in the folder `dump` means that `mongorestore` thinks they should be restored to the database `dump` (it is inferred from the path).  The verbose output even explicitly states that the data is being placed into `dump.langs` and `dump.tweets` specifically.

If you specify the database you wish to restore to (with `-d`) and restore the specific files you will be able to restore the documents to the database you desire.  Or, you can simply have a look in the dump database by running:

```
use dump;
db.tweets.find();
db.langs.find();
```